# Intervention imagecache is buggy on the production server L5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using intervention imagecache. However, it works as desired on my local development environment, but not on production. I have created custom templates:

```
class NewsFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function applyFilter(Image $image)
    {
        return $image->fit(135, 135);
    }
}
```

added it to

```
'templates' => array(
    'small' => 'Intervention\Image\Templates\Small',
    'medium' => 'Intervention\Image\Templates\Medium',
    'large' => 'Intervention\Image\Templates\Large',
    'news' => 'App\Filters\NewsFilter',
),
```

did `composer dumpautoload -o` / `artisan route:clear` / `artisan cache:clear` / `artisan view:clear`

Nothing helped. On local it shows right dimensions 135x135px, but on production it's 50x50

You can check it here: http://sportus.cash/news

all images are 50x50, though they should be 135x135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was cache issues.

`php artisan cache:clear` didn't work due permissions issues: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1179

So i went to `storage/framework/cache` and removed everything manually.